# How to properly split a Vuejs component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, refactoring

So, I've got a huge Vue file which do more than 1500 lines CSS excluded.

This file is a wrapper for a lot of other components but mostly can't be breaked into smaller components.

The things is I still got some logics like groups of methods which could be extracted. However it has impact on some data or watched properties.

Is it possible to export differents parts of my file and use them as a more "global import".

Something which would be like :

```
// components/component.logicX.vue/js?
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            ....
        }
    },
    methods: {
        aFewMethods(){ this.data = "something" },
        ...
    },
    watch: {
        ...
    } 
}
```

```
// component/component.vue
import logicX from '.component.logicX.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        logicX
    },
    data() {
        data: '' //this data is modified from a logicX component method.
    }

}
```

Comment: You can use [mixins](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html) to accomplish this.

Comment: To extract/reuse component logic, give a look at the [Composition API](https://vue-composition-api-rfc.netlify.com) proposed for Vue 3. It allows you to extract and reuse logic and lifecycle methods. You can use the API in Vue 2 with the [@vue/composition-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue/composition-api) plugin.

Comment: I'll have a look at this new feature @CMS. But don't you think its a bit dangerous either because its not stable yet or because it could be not the syntax as the one used in V3 ?

Comment: @Baldráni, Yes, you are right, the API might still change, but IMO the RFC is pretty stable now. Vue 3 is in development now. They just released the [source code recently](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next). I would prefer, for instance, to start using these features rather than extracting logic to mixings.